# How best to model a (very) sparse probability density function?

Tags: c, paging, memory-address, probability-density

I want to write a traffic generator that replicates the primitive read and write demands that are made on memory by a running computer.

But running computers also show (very strong) locality in their memory references and across a  64 bit address space only a very small range of addresses will be referenced (in fact I have tested this on on one benchmark and about 9000 pages of the billions on offer are touched).

What is a good way to model such a sparse probability density function (in C or C++ ideally) - I have probabilities for the benchmark but don't need to follow them too closely (as I could just use the benchmark references in any case but want something a bit more flexible).

**To clarify** I also have data about how many reads should come from each page, but what I am interested in is picking the sequence of pages. (The Markov chain idea suggested in the comments might be the way to do this)

Comment: Maybe Markov chains ?

Comment: This isn't entirely clear; a sparse (discrete) PDF is just a sparse vector.  A hash-map is one way to implement that.

Comment: After an acces to page a the next access will be to page a, (prob=x) or to page b (prob=y), etc. Same for page b,c, etc. --> Markov

Comment: Talking about a PDF suggests that you want to model just the first-order probability of each memory location being accessed.  But memory accesses are *far* from independent in any real program (that's why caches are effective) so if you want something that approaches the behaviour of a real program, you'll need to take temporal locality into account, e.g. via Markov chains as wildplasser suggested.

Comment: Yes, I have data about the size/sequencing of the accesses too - I suppose what I mean is, how to decide which page to hit next. On the first hit of page I can also decide how long the reference will be.

Comment: OK, let's say I go with the Markov chain idea. How do I decide which page is next when a lot might have the same probability of access. I don't need to model the real physical process too closely - this is to test algorithms in a general way, not to precisely model a real system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth I decided to use a pretty crude hack - along these lines: pick a random number between 1 and 0, find the element in the distribution that has a frequency/probability equal or greater than this number (picking the minimum probability of all elements in this set). Seems to work (I did this in R)